# Gibbs models for numerically marked data?

Tags: model, statistics, spatial, disk, spatstat

I am analyzing data similar to the "anemones" data in spatstat, where my data also consists of disks of varying diameters. My goal is to test for significant regularity, or inhibition between disks. Right now I have tried fitting Strauss models to the data, but was wondering if there is any way I can make the interaction distance somehow dependent on the numerical marks of the data? The models indicate that there is significant regularity at my chosen interaction distance, but some of them have lack of fit issues which I suspect would be improved if the size variation of the disks were to be taken into account. Any advice on strategies for creating models of such data would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not yet implemented in `spatstat`. It is on the "to do" list...